# neo4j cypher strange behaviour

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i just encountered an odd behaviour in neo4j 
when i run this query

```
match (n)-[rel:HAS_A|HAS_DIPNOT *]->(c) where id(n) = 9457 return c
```

it returns expected nodes and relations..

however when i run this:

```
match (n)-[rel:HAS_DIPNOT *]->(c) where id(n) = 9457 return c
```

it returns nothing as can be seen on the screen capture..
[image: n4j]

do you have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Which relationships does the node with id 9457 have?

I presume it only has `:HAS_A` relationships. So your second query cannot traverse out the single step needed until there are `:HAS_DIPNOT` to continue on.

The nodes you highlighted have other id's.

Comment: Yes it has ':HAS_A' relationship.. How can i change the query in order to check if a node eventually connects to anoher node with a specific relationship?

Comment: Try `match (n)-[rel]->(c) where id(n) = 9457 return type(rel), count(*)` and try to leave off the direction.